# Combine two arrays into keys and values in a resulting array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, one with the keys and the other with the values:

```
key_array = ['key1','key2','key3']
values_array = ['val1','val2','val3']
```

How do I iterate through them (their size will vary) to obtain this:

```
array('key1' => 'val1',
      'key2' => 'val2',
      'key3' => 'val3')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$a = array('green', 'red', 'yellow');
$b = array('avocado', 'apple', 'banana');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c);
?>


Array
(
    [green]  => avocado
    [red]    => apple
    [yellow] => banana
)
```